# Python for GIS on thumb-drive

Tags: python, software-recommendations

I'm looking at putting together a light Python install on a thumb drive that I can take to client offices and do some basic GIS processing. I'm thinking of installing the following:

- PyScripter
- Python 2.6/2.7
- Numpy
- Scipy
- GDAL/OGR with the Python bindings
- GRASS, likewise with the Pythong bindings
- QGIS

Does anyone have any suggestions of any libraries / software that might be a useful addition?

Typically I'll be working with raster datasets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Portable Python** http://www.portablepython.com/

Interesting project you have will it be available to the GIS community?

Maybe of interest
Portable GIS
http://www.archaeogeek.com/blog/portable-gis/

Answer (score 5):

- [Shapely](http://trac.gispython.org/lab/wiki/Shapely) for quick geometry work
- [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) because spreadsheets are ubiquitous

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly advice SAGA GIS as a portable tool for doing GIS analysis. There is a python interface also - though quite a lot of things can be done using the modules present.
http://www.saga-gis.org

Answer (score 0):

BTW, there is already slaxGIS: http://geomatica.como.polimi.it/software/slaxGIS/index.php

It comes with GRASS 6.4.0, MapServer 5.6.5, OpenLayers 2.10, uDig 1.2.0, OpenJUMP 1.3.1, Zoo WPS 1.0.0, PostgreSQL 8.4.4, PostGIS 1.5.2, and libraries such as Proj, GDAL/OGR etc.

Maybe it is easier to either customize that or to ask the authors to include new packages in case some space is left.